# Can NLog receive a variable, whose value changes at run time, from a C# application? Ex. a batch Id

Tags: c#, winforms, nlog

Can a C# application pass NLog a variable, at runtime, that can be then used as input for insertion into a database?
Ex. I have an application where it receives, during the processing of files, a unique batch Id as a command line parameter.  Multiple occurrences of this executable can be launched at the same time and each one will receive its own Batch ID.  For the sake of troubleshooting ... I REALLY need to have NLog pass that Batch Id to the insertion of the log(s).
I saw there was a ${var} [layout renderer](https://nlog-project.org/config/?tab=layout-renderers) but that is meant to already be defined within the config file.  Well all of these executables will be sharing the same config file.  So that doesn't seem to be a solution.
Any assistance and code examples (or links to examples) are appreciated.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Anyone ... is this example <a href="https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/772"> Logging with runtime parameters to Database </a> for what I am looking for?  That is does the NLog.config stay the same for all occurrences of the running application?

#772 "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your `batchId` is global to the process, so you could check out the [`Gdc layout renderer`](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Gdc-Layout-Renderer).

> Global Diagnostic Context - a dictionary structure to hold per-application-instance values.
>
> Platforms Supported: All (NLog 4.1 allows storing any Object type, not just String)
>
> Use the Global Diagnostics Context when you want to make certain information available to every logger in the current process.

The documentation has explains how to use it, but very briefly: In your configuration file you would use `${gdc:item=batchId}` where you want to put the `batchId` in your logs. Then, somewhere in the application (in the `Main` function, I'd wager) you'd do: `GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("batchId", batchId);`.

I don't know off hand the namespace where `GlobalDiagnosticsContext` lives.

If `GlobalDiagnosticsContext` is too broad, there is also [Mapped Diagnostics Logical Context (MDLC)](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/MDLC-Layout-Renderer) (Replaces the legacy MDC, as MDLC also supports async Tasks)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  That may be what I am looking for.  I will wait to see if anyone else has other suggestions before marking this as the solution.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'm using the 'MDLC' - https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/MDLC-Layout-Renderer - for stuff like request IDs/correlation IDs. It's probably what you're after. If you only have one batchId at the time in the whole application (no threads/tasks that work on different batches) you can use the Global context instead.

Comment: @gnud - Thanks for the clarification of MDLC vs Global context.  I am starting to believe Global context will be the way to go (since my application will just be ran multiple times at the same time with different batch Ids passed to each).  I would assume that these Layout Renderer parsing strings can be used anywhere anywhere within the <target></target> tags.  Correct?

Comment: Yes, I use it both in the `fileName` and `layout` attributes on the `<target>` tag.

Comment: Note that you should avoid the MDC in async code. Use the MDLC instead.

Comment: @user13116244 You can also use it in variables, to simplify the rest of the config file. For example, `<variable name="batchId" value="${gdc:item=batchId}" />`. Then you can reference  `$batchId` in your format string, later.

Comment: @user13116244 Is batch id per application instance? If yes, then Gdc might be good for you.

Comment: @gnud Thanks for the additional code examples and feedback.  Since <a href="https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Gdc-Layout-Renderer"> GDC </a> is defined as "per-application-instance values" ... I am confident this will be what I am looking for.  I will try this code out today.